# Updating Plesk: How do I save a file to my virtual server's hard drive?

Tags: save, plesk, hard-drive, virtual-server

I'm in the process of updating Plesk from 10.3.1 to the latest version (10.4)

In the Plesk instructions it says I have to save an installer to my server's hard drive:

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-guide/index.htm?fileName=65789.htm

..but I have no idea how to do this. I realise this is probably a very silly question but being new to virtual servers and web hosting in general I'm not sure what to do.

Your help would be hugely appreciated :)

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is what you can find on Parallels web site

Download Option 1: "One-Click" installer

Use the One-Click Installer utility to perform a clean installation of the Panel in one step into any Linux OS. The utility automatically determines your operating system and installs the latest version of an appropriate distributive in the typical configuration.
One-Click Installer works only on Linux OSes.
To install the Panel, run one of the following commands on behalf of the superuser:
- If you have the wget utility, run
      wget -O - http://autoinstall.plesk.com/one-click-installer | sh
- If you have the curl utility, run
      curl http://autoinstall.plesk.com/one-click-installer | sh
- If you have the fetch utility, run
      fetch -o - http://autoinstall.plesk.com/one-click-installer | sh

The installer can be downloaded via web interfaces as well

[Original source](http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/)